# Is it possible to click through an IFrame?

Tags: css, html, events, dom, pointer-events

So, I basically have a button inside an iframe, which is as big as the screen. Now I want to be able to click the button(in the iframe) and also interact with the page behind the iframe.
I am open for any suggestions!

Comment: "and also interact with the page behind the iframe" What does this mean? Normally there isn't anything "behind" an iframe to interact with.  Is the iframe positioned at a higher z-index such that it overlaps content in the parent window? (And if so, why?)

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a chrome extension that creates an overlay for a website, like a sidebar, but i dont want the css etc. of a website to interact with my HTML. 
Up to now I tried to do that with the help of an iframe(in the foreground), but the user cant click through that.
The next thing I would try is to load the webpage into an iframe and my HTML as the actual website.
But I am certain, there is a more "clean" way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, I can see the logic behind trying to use the iframe as a CSS cordon -- but I think the drawbacks are going to outweigh the benefits there; you'll be better off drawing your overlay into the same document with highly specific CSS rules to prevent them being accidentally overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a way to do this unfortunately. You can set `pointer-events: none;` on the iframe but that prevents you from interacting with it at all.

Depending on your needs, you could make sure the iframe is literally only as big as the button with no scrolling, no border, etc. That's probably your best bet if you need to iframe it.

You could, theoretically, get the X/Y coordinates of the button from the edge of the frame, and dynamically set the `pointer-events: none;` style if the mouse is over the frame but outside those coordinates, but… that's probably the most error-prone thing I've ever written out, shame shame shame.

Your overall best bet is to not do this, and to take the button/form/link code and host it yourself, or access it via some other API that's not hacking a partial pointer event based solution together. Next to that, just shrink the iframe to the same literal size as the button.

Comment: This is the right answer. Basically don't do what you were thinking of doing and do it another way